# Weak SSL/TLS key exchange -Vulnerability on Linux server

Tags: linux, ssl

We have observed below vulnerability in RHEL 7.9 servers and need help to close it.

Vulnerability:- Weak SSL/TLS key exchange
Protocol:- TSLv1.2
Name:- DHE
Key Size:- 1024
Expected Solution:- Ciphers with Key size 2048 bits for DHE.

Thank You,
Rupesh

Answer (score 0):

for `java` app, you can apply the following to resolve your issue:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048"
```

However, this requires at least `JDK/JRE: 7/8` to apply the parameter

You can refer to this doc for more reference: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1498223

Thanks